# Why do i get "can modify frozen Array" Runtime Error when launching rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime, rspec-rails

I get this error when I launch rspec spec/models in the console.

> An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
>   Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',
>   **FILE**)
>
> RuntimeError:   can't modify frozen Array

I found where was the mistakeby reviewing everything i modified and it was a missing do in my routes.rb

```
resources :templates
  resources :template_items
end
```

but I can't understand why this type of error kept appearing. It clearly doesn't show where the error comes from, and I can't find the relation between these two things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do:

```
resources :templates do
  resources :template_items
end
```

Assuming there isn't a 'do' or 'begin' that you've not linked, at the moment you have too many 'ends' which means the file won't load.

Comment: Yes, i know, I left it incorrect on purpose, if you check the explanation above I say there was a missing "do". The thing is that I don't know why I got that type of error, that's all.

Comment: My bad didn't read properly - do you definitely have the right number of 'ends' for your 'dos'? Try removing an 'end' and seeing if you get the same result

Comment: Tried what you've told me and the error message changes. If there is no 'end' resources :template_items is not nested inside templates and my routes are wrong

Comment: Are you using FactoryGirl for your tests?

Comment: Well, i use FactoryBot (I think they are the same, no?)

Comment: Sorry that's right FactoryBot as they've now called it - https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/issues/247 - seems some people were getting your error when a factory wasn't properly defined

Comment: If you post the full error trace does it start in any models? If so that's the one with a malformed factory definition

Comment: Interesting, but it's odd that the factories are wrong. The thing is that when I ran the 'rails g scaffold...' this generated also the factories with all the neccessary. E.g 
this is for template item
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :template_item do
    body "MyText"
    category 1
    name "MyString"
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when tried to upgrade from `rails 5.2.0 to 5.2.2.1` using `bundle update rails` command, its also updated many other gems one of them was factory_bot from 4.10.0 to 5.0.2 so solution was to downgrade to 4.10.0 by specifying the version number for factory_bot to   `gem "factory_bot_rails", "~> 4.10.0"`